# Git clean/smudge filters for ansible vault secrets

Tags: git, ansible, gitattributes, ansible-vault

I am trying to setup [clean/smudge filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) in git to have automatic encrypting and decrypting of files containing secrets thru [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#encrypting-unencrypted-files) command.

Peculiarity of the ansible-vault command is that it is not idempotent (it creates a different binary each time it is invoked on the same data).

I started with the implementation suggested in [this blog page](https://leucos.github.io/articles/transparent-vault-revisited/). Unfortunately it did not work correctly, as whenever smudge is called (be it a git checkout , or just git status), the secret files looks as modified for git, even if it is not.

So I wondered if git would be comparing the binary he has in the index with the clean filtered current file, and I tried to build on those script like follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
# clean filter, it is invoked with %f

if [ ! -r "$HOME/.vault_password" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

tmp=`mktemp`
cat > $tmp

# get the plain text from the binary in the index
tmphead=`mktemp`
git show HEAD:$1 > $tmphead
contenthead=`echo "embedded" | ansible-vault view $tmphead --vault-password-file=$HOME/.vault_password`
export PAGER=cat
echo -n "$contenthead" | tee $tmphead

# if current and index plain text version differ
if [ "`md5sum $tmp | cut -d' ' -f1`" != "`md5sum $tmphead | cut -d' ' -f1`" ]; then
  tmpcrypt=`mktemp`
  cp $tmp $tmpcrypt
  # generate a new crypted blob
  echo "embedded" | ansible-vault encrypt $tmpcrypt --vault-password-file=$HOME/.vault_password > /dev/null 2>&1
  cat "$tmpcrypt"
else
  # just return the HEAD version
  cat "$tmphead"
fi

rm $tmp $tmphead $tmpcrypt
```

The difference here is that it tries to compare the current and HEAD versions of the plain text (unencrypted) secret files, and only in case they differ output a new binary blob encrypted with ansible-vault.

Unfortunately, after this change git continues to think the secret file is always modified. Even after `git add`ing the file again, so that the git blob is computed, git thinks the file is different and let the change go into the commit. Note that `git diff` return empty changes, as it should.

For reference, this is smudge:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -r "$HOME/.vault_password" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

tmp=`mktemp`
cat > $tmp

export PAGER='cat'
CONTENT="`echo "embedded" | ansible-vault view "$tmp" --vault-password-file=$HOME/.vault_password 2> /dev/null`"

if echo "$CONTENT" | grep 'ERROR: data is not encrypted' > /dev/null; then
  echo "Looks like one file was commited clear text"
  echo "Please fix this before continuing !"
  exit 1
else
  echo -n "$CONTENT"
fi

rm $tmp
```

and this is diff:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -r "$HOME/.vault_password" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

export PAGER='cat'
CONTENT=`echo "embedded" | ansible-vault view "$1" --vault-password-file=$HOME/.vault_password 2> /dev/null`

if echo "$CONTENT" | grep 'ERROR: data is not encrypted' > /dev/null; then
  cat "$1"
else
  echo "$CONTENT"
fi
```