# Prevent git-merge between unrelated branches from importing unwanted commit history

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have 2 branches, `B` (private) and `G` (public).

Branch `B` (private) has been my main develop branch for a while, and contains all sorts of commits that include private code, proprietary algorithms and some other things that can't go public.

When I created branch `G` (public), I couldn't simply branch off of `B` (private) since that would make it's history contain all those things I listed earlier that can't go public, so I created a new branch from scratch (that is, with no parent). Then I simply imported (copied) all files exactly as they were from branch `B` (private) into branch `G` (public) and that was its first commit.

Since then, I've been developing on branch `B` (private) and whenever a new commit was made, I cherry-picked it onto `G` (public).

All of this was done in a period that I was getting started to git, so, I know I could probably have done it in a better way, but this ship has long sailed.

Since I've learned a bit more about how git works (and how it's supposed to be used), I wanted to merge `B` onto `G` (or vice-versa) so I could stop cherry-picking every single commit. So here's what I've tried:

1. Merging `B` onto `G`: this imported all of `B`'s (private) commit history onto `G`, which is unnaceptable because anyone browsing `G`'s commit history would have access to private / sensitive data / algorithms.
2. Merging `G` onto `B`: this duplicated all of the cherry-picked commits on `G` (private), which is annoying but not a big deal. But it was not enough, since trying to merge `B` onto `G` after this still imported all of `B`'s (private) commit history onto `G` (unacceptable). I thought this would created a "common parent" to those 2 branches that git would use as starting point for future merges from `B` to `G`, which was not the case.
3. Rebasing `G` off of `B`: Same problem as 1.
4. Rebasing `B` off of `G`: For every commit in `G`, a conflict was created, so this proved undoable.

TL;DR: I have 2 branches `B` which is private and contains private commits and `G` which is public. This is how they look:

```
`B` (private): a -- b -- c -- d -- m -- n -- o -- p
`G` (public): w -- x -- y  --  z -/
```

`m` is a merge commit from `G` onto `B`.

I want to "import", "merge" or "bring" commits `n`, `o`, `p` (and any other commits pushed to `B`) to `G`, without cherry-picking them one by one (a single merge commit bringing all those changes to `G` would be acceptable as long as it does not bring all of `B`'s previous history with it).

I'm not sure if there's a solution to my problem, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, truly confidential information should not be in a Git repo, but in some vault (through a Git content filter driver, [even though that can be challenging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37660094/6309)).

Having a separate Git repo is the minimum, with the private one referencing the public [one as a submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: I guess this is the way to go, haven't really considered using submodules, thanks for that!

Comment: So I did some reading about submodules and a few questions came up: If I add my proprietary / private classes as a private submodule, wouldn't everyone accessing the public repository face errors regarding that submodule not being available? Wouldn't that prevent everyone from checking out the public repo?

Comment: @Guaycuru That is what I wrote: the private repo references (adds) the public one as a submodule, not the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

What is the nature of these private commits? Are they self contained in their own files? I am assuming this is true since you have been cherry picking your commits and I hope you are not constantly dealing with merge conflicts of the nature of public algorithm/data vs private algorithm/data.

May I suggest not using branches for this and instead have separate repositories? If you care about protecting your data and algorithms, think about what could happen if another team member rebases/merges something by mistake? Also, auditing and access control become much easier if you have separate repos, since most git servers act on repo level and not branch level.

If you do decide to go for separate repos, there are two possible solutions for your proprietary information hiding:

1. Secrets like environment/configuration variables / private keys etc : These should not be in your version control system anyways. Guard them with a line in .gitignore. If you need to pass those to team-mates, use some other means of communication than VCS. This will protect your data from an inadvertent push to the public repo, while still allowing for a single push.
2. Private classes/implementations: This is tricky. You obviously wont want to gitignore them. I would probably write a git plugin for this allowing my team to do a `git public-push` or something. This gives us a lot of flexibility because then we can programatically decide what constitutes a *private* file and should not be pushed to the public repo. Alternatively, if you are paranoid about this, you can still audit and cherry pick your commits.

TL;DR - Have a separate repo instead of a separate branch and maybe right a custom git plugin. This will allow you to use a single `git push` (or for a custom plugin `git public-push` or something) and may also allow external contributors to your public repo if/when it becomes famous :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, `B`'s remote is on Bitbucket and `G`'s remote is on Github. Would that count as separated repos? Anyway, I guess you're right, separated repos (one using the other as a submodule) is probably the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: Also: private keys and password are not the problem here, as they aren't on version control. ;)